# SQL joining multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Using Microsoft SQL 2000, I will like to join multiples tables (A, B, C, and D) together.  I know table A always exists. However, I only know at least one of the table form (B, C, D) exists.

Is there any way I could do something like this to accomplish what I am trying to do?

```
Select * form table a     
If table b exists left Join table b on a.id = b.id    
If table c exists left Join table c on a.id = c.id    
If table d exists left Join table d on a.id = d.id
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to check the data dictionary views for that and use dynamic SQL

```
declare @myquery varchar(1000)

set @myquery = 'Select * from a '
if exists (select * from sysobjects where xtype='U' and name = 'b')
begin
   set @myquery = @myquery + 'inner join b on b.id = a.id '
end
if exists (select * from sysobjects where xtype='U' and name = 'c')
begin
   set @myquery = @myquery + 'inner join c on c.id = a.id '
end
if exists (select * from sysobjects where xtype='U' and name = 'd')
begin
   set @myquery = @myquery + 'inner join d on d.id = a.id '
end

exec( @myquery)
```

I've used `sysobjects`, however you are encouraged to use [Information Schema Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933204%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) instead

And, a **BIG DISCLAINER ON DYNAMIC SQL**

**Advantages**

- It gives flexibility and scalability
- It can reduce the number of lines of code written

**Disadvantages**

- It can become very complex and difficult to read. Think about quotes embedded in quotes, and other such things.
- It can have a detrimental effect on code stability. Some Dynamic SQL errors will not be known until run time. (An example of this is where you reference a non-existent table)
- Dynamic SQL code is harder to test than the equivalent static SQL. It may also be impossible to test for every possible circumstance that your Dynamic SQL will encounter, thus introducing inherent risk.
- It will be more difficult to conduct an effective impact analysis on Dynamic SQL in your code-base.
- SQL injection and misuse – Dynamic SQL is more prone to misuse, and is invariably less safe than static SQL
- The queries code within Dynamic SQL is not subject to a query plan, and as such optimisations may be missed. As such, it can be slower than the equivalent static SQL
- As the SQL query is not known until runtime, it can be harder to performance-tune SQL Dynamic code (for example, determining the indexes that might be required on a table)

Comment: +1 - I would only add this link: www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: You should avoid * usage here and instead Object_ID should be preferred.

Comment: @StackOverflow User: Not so. select * has no discernable difference over select fieldname: http://milambda.blogspot.com/2008/01/whats-wrong-with-count.html

Comment: @Lieven - Thanks you so much...The example you provide is exactly what I was look for.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the query. **The * should never be the part of the query so better to mention the column names.**

```
declare @query varchar(1000)

set @query = 'Select ColumnName from a '
if exists (select Object_ID from sys.tables where name = 'b')
begin
   set @query = @query + 'inner join b on b.id = a.id'
end
if exists (select Object_ID from sys.tables where name = 'c')
begin
   set @query = @query + 'inner join c on b.id = c.id'
end
if exists (select Object_ID from sys.tables where name = 'd')
begin
   set @query = @query + 'inner join d on d.id = a.id'
end

exec( @query)
```

Comment: Its sql 2000, `sys.tables`  only came in SQL 2005

Comment: Yes :) sysobjects is a very generic terminology. So better to use specific words during development which can be understood in specific context as a developer point of view I hope I am right :)

Comment: what @JamesWiseman is saying is that you are using `sys.tables`, wich doesn't exists in SQL 2000, so your query won't work

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do a conditional join in that way.

You can just do an ordinary LEFT JOIN.  If no row matches the join criteria, those columns will be NULL:

```
Select *
from table a 
left Join table b on a.id = b.id
left Join table c on a.id = c.id
left Join table d on a.id = d.id
```

The b.* columns may be NULL or the c.* columns may be NULL or the d.* columns may be NULL.

If you need to pick the first non-NULL column, use COALESCE:

```
Select *, COALESCE(b.SOMECOLUMN, c.SOMECOLUMN, d.SOMECOLUMN) AS SOMECOLUMN
from table a 
left Join table b on a.id = b.id
left Join table c on a.id = c.id
left Join table d on a.id = d.id
```

As commenters have said, if the tables don't exist, this doesn't work.  I think I would actually advocate going ahead and creating the tables so your schemas always match expectations.  Dynamic SQL is a pain to maintain and debug and static SQL and schemas can be interrogated to ensure they meet expectations using metadata (i.e. a procedure or view will not be valid if a table is missing, and dependencies can be viewed explicitly)

Comment: @Cade Roux - I think you misread, OP does not know if the *tables* B,C & D exist. Using dynamic SQL would be one option to solve this.

Comment: Does that work? Even when the *table* doesn't exist (rather than any rows *in* the table)?

Comment: People, please *read* the question before blindly upvoting answers.

Comment: As @Lieven said, this will definitely fail if table B, C or D don't exists

Comment: @Lieven I saw that and just assumed it was poor English.  It's actually realistic to think he would be better off creating the missing tables and letting them be empty for the purposes of avoiding dynamic SQL and having a consistent database schema (assuming he has multiple similar databases with different schemas).

Comment: @CadeRoux - you might be right but I honestly doubt it. FWIW, my I've removed my downvote until we get confirmation from OP (where you can adjust or delete your answer offcourse).

Comment: @Cade Roux - It will be very tidies for me to create empty tables since I am writing a classic asp application that needs connect to multiples databases (more than 100) that has the same exact structure but some has more tables than the other.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you mean if the results exist not the tables themselves.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEA
OUTER JOIN TABLEB ON TABLEA.id = TABLEB.id
OUTER JOIN TABLEC ON TABLEA.id = TABLEC.id
OUTER JOIN TABLED ON TABLEA.id = TABLED.id
```

you will just get nulls for the columns where the value did not match.

so you can filter with

```
WHERE TABLEB.id is not null
```

etc

Comment: No, he's talking about the tables themselves existing